# WebStorm can't recognize string type for embedded typescript code

Tags: typescript, types, webstorm

For current latest Webstorm, is typescript code is in a `.ts` file, the `string` type is recognized normally.

But if the typescript code is embedded, there is something wrong.

#### `.vue` file

[image: typescript in vue]

#### `.html` file

[image: tsx]

#### `tsconfig.json`

Since the error in above mentions `tsconfig.json`, I put my file here:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

How to config WebStorm to fix it?

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce the problem in WebStorm 2018.2.1, the sample file is located in src/<component>. Please submit an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB and provide more details about your IDE and project setup.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara Thanks, finally I deleted `node_modules` and `.idea` files, and it get fixed today. The strange thing is I did these operations yesterday, but not working.

Comment: known issue that can be related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33539, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30379

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara I found the real problem. It's not webstorm's issue, but I used [cnpm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cnpm) to install the dependencies, which causes the problem. The libraries in the downloaded `node_modules` can't be handled properly by webstorm. Now I use `npm install`, everything works for now. PS: lot of people in China uses `cnpm` for faster downloading